# Back button shows then quickly disappears

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**Issue**: Upon displaying the second view, the Back button shows and then quickly disappears.
I'd like the Back button to persist on the second view.

**Setup:**
2 views.
The button that opens the second view is done via a "Show" segue.

SecondVC:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let controller = TipJarViewController<TipJarOptions>()
        self.present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

It seems to happen because of how I'm doing the `viewDidAppear`. It seems that I'm replacing the entire view with the `self.present`. I'm not sure what to search for or modify so it can still show the Back button.

Bonus question: Wondering if I'm placing this code in the wrong section. On the transition to the second view the screen is blank for a bit and then will show the view's contents. This doesn't seem like an optimal user experience. Open to any suggestions here.

[image: Simulator view of issue.]

[image: Storyboard view]

After moving `present` to first VC via Frankenstein's suggestion
[image: After moving present to first vc]

Comment: why you are presenting from second controller ? why not direct present from first ?

Comment: Because it was the first way I figured out how to make it work. No other reason than that. A designer lurking into treacherous waters...  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to segue into the second controller and then present. Instead, `present` directly instead of `show` the controller keeping it as `rootViewController` of a `UINavigationController`. Do this on the action:

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let controller = UINavigationController(rootViewController: 
    TipJarViewController<TipJarOptions>())
    present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Edit: To add back button in `TipJarViewController`, here is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleBack))
}

@objc func handleBack() {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Ok. So that code would be in the First View Controller, tied to the button as:

`@IBAction func tipButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let controller = UINavigationController(rootViewController: TipJarViewController<TipJarOptions>())
        present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }` 

With that, I no longer see the back button, and I also now have a header bar along the first view (which I don't want). Attaching new gif in original post of what I now see.

Comment: Add back button to navigationItem of `TipJarViewController`. And it would as expected. I've added edits to show how to add a back in `TipJarViewController`

Comment: Thank you! I was having trouble with that in my app so I created a sample project and was able to get that to work! However, when I now try to do that in my app I'm having a conflict with getting the back button to show. I think it has to do with the cocoapod/framework I've brought in. I tried placing that code in the ViewDidLoad section in their View Controller but not showing. Do you have any thoughts on what's causing the conflict?
https://github.com/lionheart/TipJarViewController/blob/master/TipJarViewController/Classes/TipJarViewController.swift

Comment: @benny It has nothing to do with the library. Don't 'present' 'push` your desired TipJarViewController from firstVC instead of that blank VC.

Comment: @benny update your `viewDidAppear` with code I've given in the answer

Comment: Figured out what was going on.
I need to clean the Build folder since I was editing a Pod file. After doing that, those changes now worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I understand that I shouldn't be editing a Pod file but that'll be my next thing to figure out.